# The best way to update reference to an entity in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Imagine I have an hibernate entity that is referenced by many other entities. Now I create new entity and I want new entity to toake place of old one so it is being referenced by others in place of the old one.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Try to explain why you need to do this? And you mean new by new instance?

Comment: I want to have some entities marked as deleted, so they don't vanish altogether. I just need to insert a new Entity in place of old, now obsolete one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should deep copy(which ever way you preffer to do this) original entity set the state property to deleted and make hibernate to update the entity. Then do whatever modification to copied entity and make hibernate to save this entity. Result will be that original entity will be deleted and copied will be added as new with original references.

Comment: It's quite common to have an active/inactive strategy like uther.lightbringer is mentioning, where all entities are retained in the tables for a variety of reasons. There's even a school of thought that maintains a row should never be deleted. This can be especially important for time-related reporting and some approaches to auditing.

Comment: Edited my answer. I overlooked the fact that he wants to preserve original entity.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use an update statement on the referring entities, for example:

```
update ReferringEntity re set re.entity.id = :newId where re.entity.id = :oldId
```